# Windows.h cannot be found using Winemaker/Winelib

Tags: c++, winapi, winelib

currently i'm trying to port a Windows program to Linux, more specific a DLL. The code is written in C++ and uses many Winapi calls. Since i don't want to rebuild the whole thing from scratch i thought recompiling with Winelib is a good start and worth a try but i have never used it before. So i used Winemaker to prepare the code and create a Makefile. Using `make` prints out an error that says `windows.h` cannot be found. Well, i'm using Ubuntu right now, so of course it can't be found but i thought using `wineg++` would take care of such things by underlaying a wineapi-layer.
I read the Winelib Userguide but it seems like i don't really get the concept. 
 What am i missing here? This surely won't be the last Problem i'm encountering with Winelib

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfectly fitting solution but drdobbs.com posted in interesting article about wine, winelib and porting to Linux [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/dropping-windows-with-winelib/184401635).
So using winemaker and wineg++ is a good start but one also have to add the Compiler directive `-Iwine/include`. there are the equivalents to `windows.h` etc. hidden.
It also says that code compiled that way still needs Wine to work properly to ensure that hardcoded paths like `C:\Program Files\...` are still available. If These aren't existing, it may work without Wine, but i'm absolutely NOT sure about this.